# VSCode+Python: Run multiple processes in lockstep

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging, python-multiprocessing

I am using VS Code to debug a multiprocessing application on a remote server. When I step through the code, I currently have to select each single process and step through the code individually.

Is it possible to let each process go one step in parallel when I hit "step over/into"?

Comment: Unfortunately, VSCode does not support step-by-step debugging of multiple processes simultaneously. When you debug a multiprocessing application, you must select each process and step through the code individually. You could submit [a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python-debugger) on the VS Code GitHub repository.